# Xcode+watchkit simulation: does not support a debuggable architecture:

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

I am trying to run in Xcode both the main App (which is active in background) and the WatchkitApp (which sends requests to main App through the watchkit extension). Everything works fine in standalone, but no way to make it work simultaneously.
My main concern is to understand this message when trying to attach a process: what does this mean ?

Xcode couldn't attach to "myApp"
"myApp" does not support a debuggable architecture

Thank you.

Edit:
I just read that main app in ObjectiveC and watch app in swift is a problem: https://mkswap.net/m/blog/How+to+debug+an+iOS+app+while+the+WatchKit+app+is+currently+running+in+the+simulator

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me when an extension process was hanging around refusing to terminate. Find and kill it in the Activity Monitor.

Comment: How do you kill a process on Apple Watch with Activity Monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had that same error message, and I fixed it by resolving a bug that crashed my phone app on launch. 
I didn't think to run just the phone in debug so I got confused too.

I'm running ObjC on the phone and Swift on the Watch App.